Creating gap changes over time (start and end date)
I am still pretty new to pythons. I am trying to create a Python code to pull the extraction date in which a gap first occurred as the start_time. When the condition becomes "Y", then I would like to create an end_date based on the condition and populate the extraction date in which it became "Y". At the same time, I want to check it with previous dates before giving an end date. For example, a gap opened in Jan and closed in Feb, but it reopened in March and closed in April. Overall, I want to do a continuous check just in case I add more data in the future.
Sample Data table:



ID
sub_id
Condition
extraction_date




100
x
N
2024-01-15


100
x
Y
2024-02-01


100
y
Y
2024-02-01


101
z
N
2024-02-01


101
z
N
2024-03-16


100
x
N
2024-03-16


100
x
Y
2024-04-10


101
z
N
2024-04-10


101
z
Y
2024-05-15


102
w
N
2024-05-15


102
w
Y
2024-06-15



Overall, this is what I am expecting:
An example of a gap reopening occurs for ID 100 with sub_id of x, while a continuous gap occurs for ID 101 with sub_id of z.



ID
sub_id
Condition
extraction_date
start_date
end_date




100
x
N
2024-01-15
2024-01-15
N/A


100
x
Y
2024-02-01
2024-01-15
2024-02-01


100
y
Y
2024-02-01
2024-02-01
2024-02-01


101
z
N
2024-02-01
2024-02-01
N/A


101
z
N
2024-03-16
2024-02-01
N/A


100
x
N
2024-03-16
2024-03-16
N/A


100
x
Y
2024-04-10
2024-03-16
2024-04-10


101
z
N
2024-04-10
2024-02-01
N/A


101
z
Y
2024-05-15
2024-02-01
2024-05-15


102
w
N
2024-05-15
2024-05-15
N/A


102
w
Y
2024-06-15
2024-05-15
2024-06-15




Sort the values based on ID and sub_id and use the condition "Condition == Y" to create the groups. After that group and use transform to get the dates for the columns. Use pandas where with the first condition(Condition == Y) to remove the dates that are unnecessary.
m = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'sub_id'])['Condition'].eq('Y')
g = m[::-1].cumsum().sort_index()
grp = df.groupby(['ID', 'sub_id', g])['extraction_date']

df['start_date'] = grp.transform('min')
df['end_date'] = grp.transform('max').where(m)

End result:
 ID sub_id Condition extraction_date      start        End
100      x         N      2024-01-15 2024-01-15        NaT
100      x         Y      2024-02-01 2024-01-15 2024-02-01
100      y         Y      2024-02-01 2024-02-01 2024-02-01
101      z         N      2024-02-01 2024-02-01        NaT
101      z         N      2024-03-16 2024-02-01        NaT
100      x         N      2024-03-16 2024-03-16        NaT
100      x         Y      2024-04-10 2024-03-16 2024-04-10
101      z         N      2024-04-10 2024-02-01        NaT
101      z         Y      2024-05-15 2024-02-01 2024-05-15
102      w         N      2024-05-15 2024-05-15        NaT
102      w         Y      2024-06-15 2024-05-15 2024-06-15

Edit: A slightly modified version in case the groups don't form correctly using the first solution
m = df['Condition'].eq('Y')
g = (df.groupby(['ID', 'sub_id'])['Condition']
     .transform(lambda g: g[::-1].eq('Y').cumsum())
     .to_numpy() # or reset_index(drop=True)
    )

grps = df.groupby(['ID', 'sub_id', g])['extraction_date']

df['start_date'] = grps.transform('min')
df['end_date'] = grps.transform('max').where(m)


Nice Triky!  +1  Love it.   Using the reverse slicing [::-1] with cumsum.  Then your two dates are easily calculated using groupby-transforms.

This is great! I had a question. I have more data to this. When I run it, I get something like cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels. Do you know why I may be getting this?

I'm guessing because you have duplicates values in your index and the cumsum index is unsorted.. I changed the code to add a fix, but I'm not sure if it will work with your index. The second solution will work without any modifications.

It looks like this error is happening when we're creating the grp variable...

I know where is the problem. Try the second solution, that should work.

It's giving me the same error..

I modified the second solution. See if it works. Other than that, I can't think of anything else.

Try:
def fn(x):
    start_dates, end_dates = [], []
    start_date = None

    # Iterate over the 'Condition' and 'extraction_date' 
    for c, d in zip(x["Condition"], x["extraction_date"]):
        if c == "N":
            # if new gap, set the start date
            if start_date is None:
                start_date = d

        start_dates.append(start_date)

        if c == "Y":
            # if gap ends, set the end date and reset start_date
            end_dates.append(d)
            start_date = None
        else:
            end_dates.append(None)

    x["start_date"] = start_dates
    x["end_date"] = end_dates

    return x

# pply function to each group
df = (
    df.groupby(["ID", "sub_id"], group_keys=False)  
    .apply(fn)
    .reset_index(drop=True)  # reset index
)

print(df)

Prints:
     ID sub_id Condition extraction_date  start_date   end_dates
0   100      x         N      2024-01-15  2024-01-15        None
1   100      x         Y      2024-02-01  2024-01-15  2024-02-01
2   100      y         Y      2024-02-01  2024-02-01  2024-02-01
3   101      z         N      2024-02-01  2024-02-01        None
4   101      z         N      2024-03-16  2024-02-01        None
5   100      x         N      2024-03-16  2024-03-16        None
6   100      x         Y      2024-04-10  2024-03-16  2024-04-10
7   101      z         N      2024-04-10  2024-02-01        None
8   101      z         Y      2024-05-15  2024-02-01  2024-05-15
9   102      w         N      2024-05-15  2024-05-15        None
10  102      w         Y      2024-06-15  2024-05-15  2024-06-15


apply method  does not have include_groups parameter. This will raise an error:
TypeError: fn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_groups'
Instead, you should directly use apply(fn) without any additional arguments.

@pyshadi You're using older version of pandas

@Andrei you are right, my bad. Thanks

Would you be able to explain what the df = (df.groupby(["ID", "sub_id"], group_keys=True)
.apply(fn, include_groups=False)
.sort_index(level=2)
.droplevel(2)
.reset_index() ) is doing?

Here’s an approach to solve your problem  and find out when each "gap" starts (Condition == 'N') and when it ends (Condition == 'Y'). I am sticking to basic python without relying on pandas, which would indeed be the better choice in many real world data scenarios.
Step 1:
First import datetime to handle those dates. (you don’t want to mess around with date strings)
from datetime import datetime

Step 2:
Here is your data as a list of dictionaries (which feels like JSON but in Python)
data = [
    {'ID': 100, 'sub_id': 'x', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-01-15'},
    {'ID': 100, 'sub_id': 'x', 'Condition': 'Y', 'extraction_date': '2024-02-01'},
    {'ID': 100, 'sub_id': 'y', 'Condition': 'Y', 'extraction_date': '2024-02-01'},
    {'ID': 101, 'sub_id': 'z', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-02-01'},
    {'ID': 101, 'sub_id': 'z', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-03-16'},
    {'ID': 100, 'sub_id': 'x', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-03-16'},
    {'ID': 100, 'sub_id': 'x', 'Condition': 'Y', 'extraction_date': '2024-04-10'},
    {'ID': 101, 'sub_id': 'z', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-04-10'},
    {'ID': 101, 'sub_id': 'z', 'Condition': 'Y', 'extraction_date': '2024-05-15'},
    {'ID': 102, 'sub_id': 'w', 'Condition': 'N', 'extraction_date': '2024-05-15'},
    {'ID': 102, 'sub_id': 'w', 'Condition': 'Y', 'extraction_date': '2024-06-15'},
]

Step 3:
Convert the extraction_date strings to datetime objects.
for entry in data:
    entry['extraction_date'] = datetime.strptime(entry['extraction_date'], '%Y-%m-%d')

step 4:
Use a dictionary, start_tracker to keep track where a gap starts and ends.
start_tracker = {}

Step 5:
Loop through each entry and figure out if you are starting a new gap, ending an existing one, or just chilling in between.
for entry in data:
    key = (entry['ID'], entry['sub_id'])
    
    if entry['Condition'] == 'N':
        # new gap or continuation of existing gap
        if key not in start_tracker or start_tracker[key]['end_date'] is not None:
            # start new gap
            start_tracker[key] = {'start_date': entry['extraction_date'], 'end_date': None}
        # Update current entry with the start date
        entry['start_date'] = start_tracker[key]['start_date']
        entry['end_date'] = None
    
    elif entry['Condition'] == 'Y':
        # end gap
        if key in start_tracker and start_tracker[key]['end_date'] is None:
            # update end date for this gap
            start_tracker[key]['end_date'] = entry['extraction_date']
            entry['start_date'] = start_tracker[key]['start_date']
            entry['end_date'] = entry['extraction_date']
        else:
            # Edege case handling (not expected in your data)
            entry['start_date'] = None
            entry['end_date'] = entry['extraction_date']
    else:
        # if we get an unexpected condition then we handle it gracefully
        entry['start_date'] = None
        entry['end_date'] = None

Step 6: Display the Results
print("ID", "sub_id", "Condition", "extraction_date", "start_date", "end_date", sep="\t")
for entry in data:
    print(
        entry['ID'], entry['sub_id'], entry['Condition'],
        entry['extraction_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        entry['start_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if entry['start_date'] else "N/A",
        entry['end_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if entry['end_date'] else "N/A", sep="\t"
    )

Running the code will give you:
(venv) PS C:\Users\xxxxxxx\xxxx\src> python .\test.py

ID      sub_id  Condition       extraction_date start_date      end_date
100     x       N       2024-01-15      2024-01-15      N/A
100     x       Y       2024-02-01      2024-01-15      2024-02-01
100     y       Y       2024-02-01      N/A     2024-02-01
101     z       N       2024-02-01      2024-02-01      N/A
101     z       N       2024-03-16      2024-02-01      N/A
100     x       N       2024-03-16      2024-03-16      N/A
100     x       Y       2024-04-10      2024-03-16      2024-04-10
101     z       N       2024-04-10      2024-02-01      N/A
101     z       Y       2024-05-15      2024-02-01      2024-05-15
102     w       N       2024-05-15      2024-05-15      N/A
102     w       Y       2024-06-15      2024-05-15      2024-06-15

